# How to make sure that different severity Toasters are shown differently?

Tags: javascript, css, dojo

Context: I am using `dojox.Widget.Toaster` to show notifications in my page. There are two types of notifications, one for success and another for failure. Both have different CSS styling.

The problem is that if a user gets a failure notification first and before it disappears, there is a success notification also. What happens is that the message of the success notification gets appended in the toaster and the styling of the success notification(or whichever comes the last) gets applied to the whole toasterClip.

[Initial state of Toaster](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4QO0r.png)

[Final state of Toaster, Actual and Expected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FeYt2.png)

How can I achieve the expected result?

Comment: You will need to provide a http://codepen.io/pen/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest to use the following Toaster( growler ) , it's based on bootstrap css

easy to use and with awesome style :

git repo/Doc = https://github.com/DavidSpriggs/growler-widget-js

demo = http://davidspriggs.github.io/growler-widget-js/sample/
.

Comment: Thank you so much! :)
I was thinking of making a Toaster of my own by using the dojo Toaster. This was a lifesaver. :)

Comment: I'm happy it helps you , I use it in my own project

Comment: Hi, one follow up here. Let's say a dialog is opened in my page that has some form. Now I want to show the validation result of the form in growler. If it is wrong, I cannot hide the dialog and I have to show the growler. But when the dialog is opened, the growler does not appear. How to fix this?